# Badge process popover in review page disappears when I try to hover

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-experience, badge-progress

Badge progress popover in review page disappears when I try to hover a cursor on it.

I want to click badges shown in popover but it just hides, so annoying.

However, after you right click on the progress bar, popover does not disappear.

OS: macOS catalina 10.15.5

Browser: Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116

[image: badge progress popover disappears when i try to hover]